# Slide div/image out partially with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, slide, slidetoggle, jquery-effects

i'm facing a problem i cant solve on my own:

I got a div with a background image which i want to toggle slide up/down when the div is clicked. Problem is the image always slides up completely (100%) so it is gone. I want it to stay out 20% so you can click on it and it slides down 100% again.

I tried .animate() but it changes the aspect ratio of the picture, it wont slide out then.

I checked solutions like http://spoonfedproject.com/jquery/jquery-slide-with-minimum-height/ where divs slide in/out but it doesnt have the background picture...

Anyone got an idea? I would really appreciate it!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JmLqp/105/

HTML Code

```
<div id="contact"></div>
```

CSS Code

```
#contact{
 width:162px;
 height:336px;
 background: url(http://s18.postimage.org/kl4b1rly1/bg_contact.png) no-repeat;
}
```

JS Code

```
$("#contact").click(function () {
  $(this).hide("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track with `animate()`:

```
$("#contact").css('position', 'relative').click(function () {
    if($(this).offset().top == -250) {
         $(this).animate({'top': '0px'}, 1000);
    }
    else {
         $(this).animate({'top': '-250px'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Note that you have to set the `position` to `relative` for yourself as above.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmLqp/106/)

Comment: Oh by the way this doesn't slide back down again.  To do that, you'll probably want to store a flag and `animate` the `top` property to either `-250px` or `0` as required.

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib:  Well I did say it doesn't slide back down.  The question was about it sliding all the way out instead of only most of the way -- not about it going both up and down -- so I decided to stick with the core question.

Comment: Hyper?  Nah just explaining why I only did as much as I did :-)

Comment: How can I achieve the same in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132970/how-to-show-partial-caption-and-on-hover-slide-up-the-entire-caption Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `position: relative` to your animated div, see [**working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shaGV/1/)

```
#contact{
    position:relative;
    width:162px;
    height:336px;
    background: url(http://s18.postimage.org/kl4b1rly1/bg_contact.png) no-repeat;

}

$("#contact").click(function () {
    tp = $(this).css('top') == '0px' ? '-270px' : '0px';
    $(this).animate( {top: tp }, 1000);
});
```

**UPDATE:**
I've also updated my jsfiddle to make it both go up and down, it was a minor addition.