# How to show partial caption and on hover slide up the entire caption

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyube8aw/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>This is Image One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla commodo dolor in dui lacinia gravida.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/46ccz.jpg" />
</div>
```

How can I modify the code so the H3 stays visible until hover which scrolls the entire content up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be jQuery animate. See the example shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.box').mouseenter(function(){
   $('.caption').stop().animate({height: "94%"});
  
  
    }); 
    
    $('.box').mouseleave(function(){
   $('.caption').stop().animate({height: "15%"},  500, function() {
            });
  
    });
 });
```

```css
.box {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   margin-right: 20px;
 }
 .last {
   margin-right: 0;
 }
 .caption {
   position: absolute;
   background: #000;
   opacity: 0.7;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 90%;
   height: 15%; /* Auto can still work for the height */
   padding: 5%;
   color: #fff;
      padding-top:1%;
 }
 .full-height {
   height: 90%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>This is Image One</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla commodo dolor in dui lacinia gravida.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/46ccz.jpg" />
</div>
```

**[See on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0vdchps/1/)**

**Note:** Please go full screen on the snippet to see it at work,

Comment: This is great except when I hover away I would like it go down again without waiting a few seconds :) +1 for a /JQuery solution.

Comment: Combo of mouseEneter and mouseLeave removes the delay in response to user action. CHeck it now.

Comment: Is it CSS that will make it faster or the combination of both? I would like a fast animation

Comment: I mean from the user perspective and browser execution :) I saw the difference though... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach (without jQuery; pure CSS), would be to set a `max-height` on the `.caption` element. In addition, set a value for the `transition` property too. Then when hovering over the `.box` element, increase the `max-height` of the `.caption` element to `100%`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ct389r2/)

```
.caption {
    /* other styling.. */
    max-height: 120px;
    transition: max-height 2s ease;
}
.box:hover .caption {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

You can also transition a `min-height`:

Take a look at this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/b4u0sm4j/) to see that it works for dynamic amounts of content.

```
.caption {
    transition: min-height 1s ease;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 40px;

}
.box:hover .caption {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```